# Lost ownership of Outlook's calendar - How to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, permissions, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

My company changed the way through which we do the logon in our domain in Windows. Since that, I am unable to save any changes in appointments in Outlook.

Error message:

```
Your changes cannot be saved because you don't have permission to modify some or all of the items in this folder. Would you like to save a copy in the respective standard folder?
```

If I click "yes":

```
It was not possible to save the item. You don't have the appropriate permission to execute this operation.
```

I realized that it seems to be caused by ownership issues, very likely by the change in our Windows domain login.

I've been reading about changing ownership right-clicking calendar and going to "Properties"-share, but there's no such tab shown to me (just "General" and "Home Page").

How can I fix this issue, since I've already checked file permissions and them are ok? Thanks!

### **Further information:**

**System**: Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bit
**Software version**: Outlook 2016 MSO 16.0.4266.1001 32 bits

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your mail system is Exchange server. To Exchange organization, if the organizer's mailbox attributes have been changed due to mailbox recreating or other reasons, the organizer will not be able to update the meetings he setup before. Because it's no longer the original organizer.

In above situation, you may ask the Exchange admin to search these meetings and delete them in batches from server side, then the organizer recreates the meetings.